# Two letters can form so many things

Tags: riddle, rhyme, letters

I am only two letters, in troth,
But expanded, I can be more than both.

I might be here on behalf of a holy one,
Or one that's full of shops and houses.

I might be the shell of a noun or a brand,
Or of the noun's verb in present or past.

Neighbours and yet in estrangement,
Find me and my rearrangement.

Comment: TIL troth is archaic truth

Comment: In troth, @thecoder16 hath the right of it. Verily, hast thou e'er seen so sapient a comment?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Can you put that in American for me?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms "Yeah, ya got it bro. Y'all see how smart this dude is?" *munches burger, fires gun*

Comment: @Randal'Thor (:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect the answer(or at least part of it!) is

> ST

I am only two letters, in troth,
But expanded, I can be more than both.

> ST is two letters and is an abbreviation for words with more than 2 letters.

I might be here on behalf of a holy one,
Or one that's full of shops and houses.

> Saint and street.

I might be the shell of a noun or a brand,
Or of the noun's verb in present or past.

> Seat/sit/sat, all three words enclosed by ST (thanks Riley!) And Seat apparently is a brand, which I have never heard of (thanks Phylyp!)

Neighbours and yet in estrangement,
Find me and my rearrangement.

> S and T are next to each other in the alphabet, and they appear in the words eSTrangement (thanks Phylyp!)

Comment: Correct! But you still need to solve the 3rd verse, and there's one more clue to find in the 4th (Phylyp got it ↓)

Comment: I think the third verse is referring to rot13(frng/fvg/fng). Don't know what the brand is.

Comment: @Riley i considered that... but what about the brand?

Comment: It doesn't say the brand has anything to do with the noun/verb.

Comment: The 4 letter word is a car brand, @thecoder16

Comment: [Here](http://www.seat.com)

Comment: Once again, Phylyp is correct :-)

Comment: All done; good job! Your green checkmark will arrive within 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @Randal'Thor new meta proposal: 15 rep bounties to satisfy rand al'thor :P